# Pandas adds a empty columns when saving

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simply program in which i want to add a number to the end of a column

```
fajl = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
print (fajl)
fajl.at[len(fajl['Hrana']),'Hrana'] = 350
print (fajl)
fajl.to_csv('example.csv')
```

first print is :

```
   Hrana  Izlasci
0   1641   6500.0
1    910      NaN
2   2100      NaN
3    371      NaN
    Hrana  Izlasci
0  1641.0   6500.0
1   910.0      NaN
2  2100.0      NaN
3   371.0      NaN
4   350.0      NaN
```

this is okey, this is what i expect it to do but when i start it the second time:

```
   Unnamed: 0   Hrana  Izlasci
0           0  1641.0   6500.0
1           1   910.0      NaN
2           2  2100.0      NaN
3           3   371.0      NaN
4           4   350.0      NaN
   Unnamed: 0   Hrana  Izlasci
0         0.0  1641.0   6500.0
1         1.0   910.0      NaN
2         2.0  2100.0      NaN
3         3.0   371.0      NaN
4         4.0   350.0      NaN
5         NaN   350.0      NaN
```

It adds a new column and I dont know why. I am new to pandas so can someone explain why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add parameter `index=False` to [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for not save `index` (first column in `DataFrame`):

```
fajl.to_csv('example.csv', index=False)
fajl = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
print (fajl)
    Hrana  Izlasci
0   164.0   6500.0
1   910.0      NaN
2  2100.0      NaN
3   371.0      NaN
4   350.0      NaN
```

---

Another solution for second read csv is add parameter `index_col` for read first column as `index` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
fajl.to_csv('example.csv')
fajl = pd.read_csv('example.csv', index_col=[0])
print (fajl)
    Hrana  Izlasci
0   164.0   6500.0
1   910.0      NaN
2  2100.0      NaN
3   371.0      NaN
4   350.0      NaN
```

Comment: you're setting index=False in the to_csv function call. However, you link to the read_csv function. If this is intended, i'm completely puzzled :)